# What does this command do? ls /bin | sort | tee /tmp/lista | wc -l

Tags: linux, command-line, command

I would like to understand better what this command does, when I ran it it appeared the number 77, as shown in the image, does this represent the number of words in the list? Or is there something more to explain?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through the commands:

- `ls /bin` - lists the files in the directory `/bin`
- `sort` - sorts standard input, so in this case, sort the list of files in `/bin`
- `tee /tmp/lista` - writes standard input (the sorted list) into `/tmp/lista` and passes the list on
- `wc -l` - counts the lines (`-l` = lines), so the count of files

To sum it up, the command saves a sorted list of files `/bin` to `/tmp/lista` and prints the number of files in `/bin`.

Comment: Unless of course some madman made a file with a newline in the name in that directory. OP should read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and [why not parse ls and what to do instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: Additionally, `ls` output is already sorted, unless there's a function or alias that changes it's behaviour.